# Cannot remove underline from :hover element & cannot see text-decoration:underline in chrome inspector

Tags: css, google-chrome

My button is showing underline when hovered. Looking at the chrome inspector my CSS is being ignored but there is no other css that is setting

```
a:hover{text-decoration:none}
```

screenshot from Chrome inspector here
[image: chrome inspector screenshot]

There is more HTML and CSS below are the two snippets

HTML

```
<div class='container'>
      <br />
      <br />
      <h1 class='header center  red-text text-lighten-1'>INFOSHOT</h1>
      <div class='row center'>
        <h5 class='header col s12 light'>Better and Easier Research</h5>
      </div>
      <div class='row center'>
        <a
          href='/register'
          id='download-button'
          class='btn-large waves-effect waves-light  red lighten-1'>
          Get Started
        </a>

      </div>
```

CSS

```
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
}
```

app.css

````
    /* CSS RESET */
/* @import '@atlaskit/css-reset'; */

/* Fonts */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
/* Schemes */
/* @import './css/globalSettings.css'; */
/* Materialize */
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');

/* Custom CSS */
@import './css/overides.css';```
````

Comment: There shouldn't be a colon after `:hover`

Comment: apologies that was a typo on the description. My code did not have a colon there - I have fixed the desctription

Comment: Then we'll need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Welcome to SO but I afraid you have to trim your problem until you can reproduce it in hopefully 20 to 30 lines or below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a:hover{text-decoration:none}
```

Not this

```
a:hover:{text-decoration:none}
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in description A:hover{text-direction:none}  was what I have

Comment: sorry I downvoted by accidenyt - just upvoted hopefully that cancels it out as it was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
a.btn:hover{ text-decoration: none !important; } or
a.btn:hover{ text-decoration: none; }
```

Thanks.